# How to detect compiler

Tags: vhdl

I have to load ROM from file. Quartus can use `.mif` files directly and for the simulator I have written (a quick and dirty) `.mif` file parser with the help of textio. Is there a way to detect Synthesizer tools (Quartus in my case) and to generate textio file loader process only if it is not being compiled by the Synthesizer tool?

([the source question](http://code.google.com/p/pakorobiol/source/browse/trunk/c25Board.vhd))

Comment: Many thanks for help! To summarize: I just added -- pragma/synthesis translate_off and -- synthesis/pragma translate_on around the piece of code, that onlu should be used in a Simulator. http://code.google.com/p/pakorobiol/source/browse/trunk/c25Board.vhd

Answer (score 5):

You can detect the synthesis tool by using a pragma that is only accepted by your specific synthesis tool. For example, you can write:

```
constant isQuartus : std_logic := '1'
-- altera translate_off
and '0'
-- altera translate_on
;
```

This constant will be `'1'` only if you synthesize this using Altera's Quartus.

More about the various VHDL metacomment pragma's at: http://www.sigasi.com/content/list-known-vhdl-metacomment-pragmas

Comment: @nulleight You're welome. If this solves your problem, it would be great if you can "accept" the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to infer ROMs from your code?  If you're using the LPM functions, everything should "just work".

I use ROMs in Quartus and ModelSim without issue.  Just create a custom VHDL file for your ROM using the MegaWizard plugin and direct it to the appropriate initialization file, or directly instantiate an altsyncram component and include the init_file generic.

Then compile or simulate as normal.  I have had no problems running simulations using ModelSim (Altera version or stand-alone version) with initialized ROMs, and have not had to write any initialization code to read *.mif or *.hex files.

For reference, here is a directly instantiated ROM megafunction from a bit of my code that simulates properly in ModelSim (note the init_file generic):

```
-- Sine lookup table
sine_lut : altsyncram
generic map (
    clock_enable_input_a    => "BYPASS",
    clock_enable_output_a   => "BYPASS",
    init_file               => "./video/sine_rom-512x8.mif",
    intended_device_family  => "Arria GX ",
    lpm_hint                => "ENABLE_RUNTIME_MOD=NO",
    lpm_type                => "altsyncram",
    numwords_a              => 512,
    operation_mode          => "ROM",
    outdata_aclr_a          => "NONE",
    outdata_reg_a           => "UNREGISTERED",
    widthad_a               => 9,
    width_a                 => 8,
    width_byteena_a         => 1
)
port map (
    -- Read port
    clock0      => clk,
    address_a   => sine_addr,
    q_a         => sine_do
);
```

If you really need to do something different when simulating vs. synthesizing, there are a several ways to go about it.  For simple things, you can use something like the following directives:

```
--synthesis translate-off
<code for simulation only>
--synthesis translate-on
```

http://quartushelp.altera.com/11.1/master.htm#mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_translate.htm?GSA_pos=5&WT.oss_r=1&WT.oss=--%20synthesis%20translate_off

You should be able to find a lot of real-world examples of these directives via internet search, and I've included one example below (power-on reset is shorter when simulating vs. when running in real hardware):

```
-- Async. Power-on Reset, with de-assertion delay
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge (clk) then
        -- Create a delay at power-up
        if rst_PowerOn='1' then
            rst_pora    <= '1';
            rst_por_cnt <= (others=>'0');
        -- synthesis translate_off
        elsif rst_por_cnt(5)='1' then  -- 256 nS in simulation
            rst_pora    <= '0';
        -- synthesis translate_on
        elsif rst_por_cnt(19)='1' then -- 4ms in real hardware
            rst_pora    <= '0';
        else
            rst_por_cnt <= rst_por_cnt + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

For more complex situations, use your imagination.  Some folks use the C pre-processor, the M4 macro language, or something similar as a preliminary build step prior to synthesis/simulation.  I have makefiles and scripts that convert FileName.sim.vhdl (for simulation) into FileName.vhdl (for synthesis), processing it with some text utilities to comment/un-comment various blocks of code based on rules I crafted so I could maintain both versions in a single file (think something like an enhanced C pre-processor tweaked for use with VHDL).  Just do something that fits with your workflow and team dynamics/culture.